# Extract gzip from data file

Tags: gzip

I'm looking for some guidance on how to get this gzip out of a data file.

```
$ file cut6
cut6: data

$ binwalk cut6
DECIMAL   HEXADECIMAL    DESCRIPTION
.......................................
1       0x1   gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT), NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
```

I tried a few things just to see if I could get lucky, but no dice.

```
$ gzip -d cut6
gzip: cut6: unknown suffix -- ignored

$ gunzip cut6
gzip: cut6: unknown suffix -- ignored

$ uncompress cut6
gzip: cut6: unknown suffix -- ignored

$ zcat cut6
gzip: cut6: not in gzip format
```

.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like binwalk tells you there is an additional byte in front of the gzipped data. Ignore that byte with any method you see fit.

```
tail -c +1 cut6 | gzip -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the file format signature manually, like:
`xxd -l 4 cut6` to find/confirm a file format. Then go with 4 (this size can be different) bytes to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures . You should get `1F 8B`, but if not, then look for the right compression method and use appropriate tool to decompress/process.